# Why is it not possible to use groupBy() in an eager loading query - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, eager-loading

ErrorException:

```
stripos() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given
```

For the `groupBy()` call in the `with()` method

```
$user = User::with([
    'pricelists' => function($query) {
        $query->groupBy(function($var) {
            return Carbon::parse($var->pivot->created_at)->format('m');
        });
     }
])->where('id', $id)->get();
```

I already saw a few posts talking about how to manage this problem and that it shall not be possible to use `groupBy()` in eloquent but I do not really understand why...

To be clear:

`User` and `Pricelist` model got a many-to-many relationship with the default `timestamps()` method. I am trying to get the downloaded pricelists grouped by their months they were downloaded from the current user.

After a few attempts I just deleted the above shown `=> function($query...` statement from the `with()` method and just left the `with(['pricelist'])` to fetch all datasets and tried this:

```
$user->pricelists = $user->pricelists->groupBy(function($var) {
    return Carbon::parse($var->pivot->created_at)->format('m');
});
return $user->pricelists;
```

And it works fine and returns an array with multiple arrays for each month... But returning it like this:

```
return $user;
```

returns just 1 array with all entries... I do not really get the sense behind it right now...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two `groupBy()` method that you are using in the two code you provide are totally different methods.

The first `groupBy()` where you use it in the callback is actually being called by `$query` which is a [query builder](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries) object. The `groupBy()` here is used to add [SQL GROUP BY Statement](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) into the query. And as per the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset), it only take string variables as parameter.

The `groupBy()` in your second code is being called by `$user->pricelists` which is a laravel [eloquent collection](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-collections). The `groupBy()` method here is actually from the base collection class and is used to group the items inside the collection into multiple collections under the different key defined by the parameter passed to the function. Please read the documentation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#method-groupby).

For your case, the second `groupBy()` is the one you should be using since you plan to use a callback and will allow you to use more complicated logic.

Comment: And I was actually wondering why there are two different groupBy() descriptions in the official laravel documentation. Thanks for explaining!